# Silverlight 4 Threading Problems

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, events

recently I've been developing an application in Silverlight that uses uploading. 
I use `WebClient` class to communicate with an `HttpHandler` that is in my server. The methods provided by `WebClient` are asynchronous and use Event-based APM: having in mind that the scope of Silverlight is to have a fluid UI that doesn't blocks I wanted, for fun, to try making the calls synchronous.

### Code

```
AutoResetEvent _uploadedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

foreach (var item in _fileInfos)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            client.OpenWriteCompleted += (sender, e) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = item.OpenRead())
                    using (Stream stream = y.Result)
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

                            int readBytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            if (readBytes == 0)
                                break;

                            stream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    _uploadedEvent.Set();
                }
            };

            client.OpenWriteAsync(new Uri(_receiverUri));

            _uploadedEvent.WaitOne();
        }
```

### The Problem

This way to make the calls synchronous doesn't work in Silverlight but it does in WPF.
Right now I'm noticing I'm not the only one to have this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819650/silverlight-httprequest-thread-problem

Where do you think is the problem? 
Thanks in advance.
AS-CII.

Comment: *I wanted, for fun, to try making the calls synchronous*. I don't see anything fun in this.

Comment: I think it's a way to practice and to know better Silverlight. Is this a problem?

Comment: Try removing this `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` from your code and directly call the `OpenWriteAsync`, it's not needed. When you call OpenWriteAsync it will already use a thread from the pool. Also I bet that there's an exception occurring in your callback when you try to access `e.Result`  and you **never** actually `Set` the event. Use try/finally to ensure that the event has been Set or you will kill the poor browser waiting for a never signaled event in the main thread :-)

Comment: Already tried. It doesn't works, I used the ThreadPool because I was thinkin' that Silverlight didn't use a new thread. There aren't also exceptions, the debugger doesn't step into OpenWriteCompleted event and, if I remove the call to WaitOne, everything works fine.

Comment: As to why this works in WPF and not Silverlight it is difficult to say. One thing to remember is that Silverlight runs in a sandboxed environment and you might not have HTTP access cross domain.

Comment: You never step in the OpenWriteCompleted event because there's an error related to accessing the HTTP resource.

Comment: There's no error related to accessing the HTTP resource: my opinion is supported by the fact that without the call to AutoResetEvent.WaitOne everything works; also inserting a try/finally statement doesn't help. P.s. Thanks anyway for suggesting try/finally, I had forgotten it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Silverlight needs to rendezvous with the UI thread in order to do the web request, but the UI thread is blocked on the WaitOne call, so you have a deadlock.  (This can be construed as a Silverlight "feature".)